# What is Soul Eater's real name?

Tags: soul-eater

In the show Soul Eater, the school which Maka and Soul Eater attend, the DWMA, allows students to go by stage names. Maka chooses to go by her real name where as Soul Eater goes by a stage name. I've been wondering what Soul Eaters actual name is for ages, and never seen it mentioned in the anime.

So what is his real name? And do we ever hear of his name in the anime, manga, or through other means?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as per the [wikia](http://souleater.wikia.com/wiki/Soul_Evans) Soul's birth name is **Soul Evans**

> Soul "Eater" Evans,<sup>[[2](http://souleater.wikia.com/wiki/Soul_Evans#cite_note-1)]</sup> known formerly as Soul Eater (ソウルイーター, Souruītā) and born Soul Evans (ソウル·エヴァンス, Sōru· Evansu) is a Demon Weapon who was part of the Evans, a family of famous musicians.<sup>[[3](http://souleater.wikia.com/wiki/Soul_Evans#cite_note-Chapter_84-2)]</sup>

the citations for this ([citation 2](http://souleater.wikia.com/wiki/Soul_Evans#cite_note-1) & [citation 3](http://souleater.wikia.com/wiki/Soul_Evans#cite_note-Chapter_84-2)) is listed as Soul Eater Manga: Chapters 113 and 84 respectfully. so this information is Manga only

Answer (score 0):

The demon in part 3 or season 3 episode 9 does refer to him as Evans, so his name is also mentioned in the anime, but I think it was just that 1 time.